# Need translation Please of: Promissary of the future

Tags: classical-latin, vocabulary, syntax, english-to-latin-translation

Dear Translation Helpers, Could you please help me translate "Promissary of the Future" into true Latin?  I have looked the words up, but they don't seem to make sense as the syntax is different and I don't know how to switch the syntaxes to get a true translation.  Thank you in advance for any assistance you could provide.

If Promissary doesn't work, perhaps "Emissary" would work better?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Where do you want to use the phrase and what do you want to convey with it? The more we know about the context, the better our suggestions are.

Comment: We are suggesting a motto for the change from a training to new innovations and I would like to convey that we bring the promise of the future or a better future.  Thank you!

Comment: It might be helpful to translate it into English before asking. I've no doubt that "promissary" is listed in dictionaries, but I can't work out what you mean by it.

Comment: Is your mother tongue English? I am unsure about your usage of ‘promissary’.

Answer (score 3):

***Pignus Futurae Spei*** A pledge of future hope.

***Pignus***  a token or pledge, a solemn word used by Cicero and Vergil.
[Nominativus pignus pignora. Genitivus pignoris pignorum ... Vocativus pignus pignora]

> Owen *Pneumatologia* 1674:*hoc in donorum operationibus futuræ spei pignus est* this, in the effects of those gifts, is a pledge of future hope
>
> Valerius Maximus: *vel spei vel desperationis pignus fuerit* it was a token of either hope or desperation
>
> Cicero:   (Philippics 1/4/3)
>   *magnum pignus libertatis*;  a great token of the liberty [of the Roman people]
>
> Vergil (Ae.11.363) *solum, pacis inviolabile pignus*: our soil, an unbreakable pledge of peace

Comment: It is worth mentioning that the pronunciation of spēī is monophonic, ɔ: not as in English _hay_ but as in Latin poetic _mē in_.

Comment: I didn’t notice at the time, but I erroneously wrote ‘monophonic’ when I meant ‘monophthongal’. Better late than never.